# Finding largest triangular submatrix in binary matrices

Tags: matrices

The input of my problem is a 0/1 matrix.
The problem consists in finding the largest triangular submatrix.

In my problem, a square matrix is called triangular if all the entries below (or above) the main diagonal (or the off diagonal) are zero and all the entries on the diagonal are equal to one.

For example, in the following matrix 
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1&1&1&1\\1&0&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1&1\\1&0&1&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}, $$
there is an obvious 3x3 triangular submatrix $M([3,4,5],[4,5,6])$ but there also is a less obvious 4x4 triangular submatrix $M([2,3,6,4],[4,2,1,5])$.

For a given matrix, is there a known algorithm to find the largest triangular submatrix?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what "triangular submatrix" means?

Comment: The matrix $M([2,3,6,4],[4,2,1,5]) = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1 & 1\cr 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr}$ is indeed upper triangular, but $M([3,4,5],[4,5,6]) = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 1 & 1\cr 1 & 1 & 1\cr}$ is neither upper nor lower triangular.  Perhaps you meant $M[(5,4,3],[4,5,6])$?

Comment: Of course, any matrix that is triangular in any of the four possible ways (upper, lower, "top left" or "bottom right") can be made upper triangular by reversing the order of its rows and/or columns, so you might as well ask for upper triangular.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, exactly, I meant triangular in any of the four possible ways.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it seems my problem has been studied in [the following paper](http://rdcu.be/o0mF):

- M. C. Golumbic,T. Hirst, M. Lewenstein, [Uniquely Restricted Matchings](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00453-001-0004-z), Algorithmica, Volume 31, Issue 2, October 2001.

The authors proved the problem of finding the largest triangular submatrix is NP-complete. However, they do not provide any algorithm.